# Reduce duplication in media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a site with 3 themes: dark, light, and system. System selects between dark and light based on a media query against `prefers-color-scheme`. The root html will have a class of `theme-system`, `theme-light`, or `theme-dark`. Currently my css looks like this

```css
html {
    --dark-background:   #212121;
    --dark-text:         #bdbdbd;

    --light-background:   #bdbdbd;
    --light-text:         #212121;
}

.theme-system, .theme-dark {
    --background:   var(--dark-background);
    --text:         var(--dark-text);
}

.theme-light {
    --background:   var(--light-background);
    --text:         var(--light-text);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
    .theme-system {
        --background:   var(--light-background);
        --text:         var(--light-text);
    }
}
```

Notice that I only use `--dark-background` in a single place, but I have to use `--light-background` in two places. If I didn't need to do this, I could remove the indirection through `--dark-*`/`--light-*` and simplify the whole deal. Is there a way to do this?

I'm attempting to get to something like this pseudocode

```css
.theme-system, .theme-dark {
    --background:   #212121;
    --text:         #bdbdbd;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) .theme-system, .theme-light {
    --background:   #bdbdbd;
    --text:         #212121;
}
```

Comment: Just an opinion, I find your original scheme more easily maintainable as it is obvious where the color settings are and a subsequent maintainer only has to change these without having to dig further into the code.

Comment: `@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) .theme-system, .theme-light` - this kind of "half media query, half rule" syntax doesn't exist. A CSS _preprocessor_ could of course help you with not having to explicitly _write_ the same code in two different locations, if you make use of some include/extends syntax.